# Possible causes of Cannot read property constructor of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to iterate over all the forms present in a div. So I am using the following code for this

```
$('#divid form').each(function (index, formDetails) {
    if (formDetails) {
        console.log($(formDetails).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

This is working fine in Mozilla with no issues but when I run this code in Chrome sometimes it throws the following error.

This error is coming

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined

I am using Version 33.0.1750.117 m of Chrome.

Why this error is coming I am not able to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have jQuery included before your try and load your functions.

Wrap your javascript code inside the below function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     alert('loaded');
 }
```

Also check if the initial is $ or jQuery

Comment: I am using backbone framework with require.js All the files are loaded properly.

Comment: Try to use console.log messages inbetween your codes to check at which line the error exist.